# Computer Networking count to infinity problem

Tags: networking, count, routes, infinity

c.  Below are the portion of the routing tables for the packets with destination C. The first line of the routing tables are the values before the indicated link broke. Fill in the rest of the table assuming that poison reverse is not used

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xGoh.png)